Serverpod Request Interceptor
How do I include a request interceptor to a Serverpod server.
For example, I would like to check all request to the server to ensure that they are a POST method before proceeding.
I know I can do this from the endpoint classes, but I would rather want to have it in a global scope for all endpoints.
Regards.
